# I have a user info command, and have the created at date using .createdAt. I can't stylize this as I've done previously

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have a user info command on my bot, and use a stylized .createdAt, as per help by another user on here. This works for the message.author, but not for what I've defined as memberInfo, which is used when a user is mentioned. `let memberInfo = message.mentions.members.first();` defines it, and I stylize it with `const date = message.author.createdAt; 
const newDate = date.toLocaleDateString();`. How could I make it so the memberInfo createdAt is not just the normal string of timezone and time etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want

```
   new Date(newDate).valueOf() //1554418800000
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend using [`dateformat`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat) for a lot more customization easily.

To answer your question, use `message.mentions.users.first()`. If you already have a member object, you could simply use the `user` property, i.e. `member.user`. Your code should look something like this...

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;

const date = user.createdAt.toLocaleDateString();
```

Keep in mind it's good practice to properly parse arguments instead of using `message.mentions`. If mentioning the bot is allowed as a prefix, your current code would return the bot instead of the intended user.